# Android Error [Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar' on a null object reference] android

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have a code module which implements list view in simple activity, however when I run the code I get the following error:

```
7-23 09:12:25.123  13642-13642/com.example.kmi_dev.fbloginsample D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
07-23 09:12:25.123  13642-13642/com.example.kmi_dev.fbloginsample E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.kmi_dev.fbloginsample, PID: 13642
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.kmi_dev.fbloginsample/com.example.kmi_dev.fbloginsample.Home}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference
            at com.example.kmi_dev.fbloginsample.Home.onCreate(Home.java:79)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'void android.app.ActionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(boolean)' on a
>   null object reference
>               at com.example.kmi_dev.fbloginsample.Home.onCreate(Home.java:79)

points to this line.

```
// enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

> android:theme="android:Theme.Light"

How can I got the action bar in my listview activity?

Comment: The pastebin.com link has been deleted, so I am marking this question as off-topic (specifically that the problem needs to be contained within the question).

Answer (score 1):

Try using `getSupportActionBar()` instead of `getActionBar()`.